# Como establecer el source de una imagen desde un elemento de un objeto

Tags: javascript, imagen, react-native

Tengo un JSON con bastantes proveedores, donde cada uno tiene un id, un nombre de proveedor y una imagen.
Quiero mostrar el la imagen de dicho proveedor segun el id de este.

Basicamente, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<View style={styles.logo}>
   <Image style={styles.imagen} source={proveedores[proveedor]} />
</View>
```

Este es el json, que lo importo al codigo como coches:

```
[
    {"id":9, "proveedor": "Avis", "img":"Avis_logo.png"},
    {"id":11, "proveedor": "Atesa", "img":"atesa_logo.png"},
    {"id":17, "proveedor": "Hertz", "img":"hertz.png" },
    {"id":18, "proveedor": "Europcar", "img":"Europcar.png" },
    {"id":38, "proveedor": "SixtRentaCar", "img":"sixt.png" },
    {"id":106, "proveedor": "AutosXoroi", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":111, "proveedor": "Drivania", "img":"drivania.png"},
    {"id":214, "proveedor": "CentauroRentaCar",  "img":"centauro.png" },
    {"id":1406, "proveedor": "GT1Rent", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":2827, "proveedor": "AsionTravel", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png"},
    {"id":3931, "proveedor": "Click&Rent", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":3980, "proveedor": "LaSavinaCarsMotors", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6029, "proveedor": "OneCarsValencia", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6129, "proveedor": "FlexibleAutos", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6134, "proveedor": "AutoArandino", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6249, "proveedor": "Rentikar", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6285, "proveedor": "Transferextra", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6432, "proveedor": "SCMelaniaRentaCar", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6579, "proveedor": "GoldcarSpain", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" },
    {"id":6662, "proveedor": "Telefurgo", "img":"alquiler_de_coches.png" }
]
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
import coches from "../../assets/json/coches.json";

this.state={
   coches: coches
}

const proveedores = {
            Avis: "../../assets/images/proveedores/Avis_logo.png",
            Atesa: "../../assets/images/proveedores/atesa_logo.png",
            Hertz: "../../assets/images/proveedores/hertz.png",
            Europcar: "../../assets/images/proveedores/Europcar.png",
            SixtRentaCar: "../../assets/images/proveedores/sixt.png",
            AutosXoroi: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            Drivania: "../../assets/images/proveedores/drivania.png",
            CentauroRentaCar: "../../assets/images/proveedores/centauro.png",
            GT1Rent: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            AsionTravel: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            Click: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            LaSavinaCarsMotors: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            OneCarsValencia: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            FlexibleAutos: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            AutoArandino: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            Rentikar: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            Transferextra: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            SCMelaniaRentaCar: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            GoldcarSpain: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png",
            Telefurgo: "../../assets/images/proveedores/alquiler_de_coches.png" 
        }

        const codigoRent = this.props.idProveedor; //esto es 38 = SixRentaCar
        let proveedor = "";

        this.state.coches.forEach((agencia) => {
            if (agencia.id == codigoRent) { //si agencia.id=38 == codigoRent=38
                proveedor = agencia.proveedor; //Aqui proveedor es SixtRentaCar
            }
        });

<View style={styles.logo}>
   <Image style={styles.imagen} source={proveedores[proveedor]} />
</View>
```

Como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Has probado así: `<Image style={styles.imagen} source={require(proveedores[proveedor])} />`?

Comment: require() no permite el uso de variables, solo acepta cadenas de texto

Comment: tambien he intendado usar uri: pero no he obtenido ningun resultado @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA

Comment: Desconozco react, pero ¿no puedes asignar directamente la imagen en el ciclo, de modo que solo uses esa variable en la vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo esto ha sido causa de un mal debugging por mi parte, fallo de novato. El error residia en el if, codigoRent era undefined y nunca se llegaba a asignar un proveedor.

Por favor no seais como yo e id paso a paso!